# short-circuit evaluation in leon --xlang

Tags: leon

Consider the following complicated way of negating a boolean (which depends on [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)):

```
def negate(a: Boolean) = {
  var b = true
  a && { b = false; true }
  b
} ensuring { res => res != a }
```

If I test this code in the Scala console, it works as expected.
But `leon --xlang` says that the postcondition is invalid.
Is this expected/specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the (simplified) encoding after the xlang transformation phase, we get the following:

```
  def negate0(a0 : Boolean): Boolean = {
    val b1 = true
    val b2 = false
    b2
  } ensuring {
    res19 => res19 != a0
  }
```

The first `b1` corresponds to the initialization `var b = true`. The second `b2` is introduced to correspond to the assignment `b = false`. Unfortunately XLang does not do any special treatment of `&&` and `||` operators meaning that it will extract all side effects in sub-expression and move them in order to the "top" level (hence why you have the `val b2 = false`). The final returned value is `b2`, the last known name of `b`, and obviously the expression `a && ...` is ignored (except for side-effect).

So basically this is a limitation in Leon, and we will be looking into fixing it.

Edit:
Note that this got fixed in the most recent version of Leon: https://github.com/epfl-lara/leon/commit/2485477f4e91cba7fe6e0c137817d62f513a3c42